# Laravel | Form not submitting to route given in action

Tags: laravel, forms, controller

I'm trying to submit a form to the right route using the action:

```
<form action="{{ route('document.destroy', $d->id) }}" method="POST" style="display: inline;">
{{ method_field('DELETE') }}
{{ csrf_field() }}
<span type="text" value="" class="btn btn-success" readonly="readonly">
     {{ $d->file_name }} ({{ $d->file_size }}) <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
</span>
<button class="btn btn-xs btn-default" type="submit" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Verwijder" onclick="return confirm('Weet je zeker dat je dit document wilt verwijderen')"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></button>
</form>
```

But yet it links to a different controller. What am I doing wrong?

I also specified the controller in the routes file:
`Route::resource('document', 'DocumentController');`

To add more context: this view gets passed from a different controller than I want to use for the DELETE function.

Comment: Why'd you sending a `$d->id` in POST method ?

Comment: Because it requires me to pass a variable.

Comment: Can show the route for your controller from which this form is getting loaded?

Comment: It's getting loaded from: Route::resource('visiting-reports', 'VisitingReportController'), but I want to use a different resource to delete a row since it's already using the delete function in that controller for something else.Instead I would like to route it to: Route::resource('document', 'DocumentController');

Answer (score 0):

for `deleting` you can try this

```
 <form action="{{action('DocumentController@destroy', $d->id)}}" method="post">
                            {{csrf_field()}}
                            <input name="_method" type="hidden" value="DELETE">
                            <button class="btn btn-danger" type="submit">Delete</button>
                            </form>
```

and `Destroy method`

```
   public function destroy($id)
        {
            $doc= Document::find($id);
            $doc->delete();

            return redirect('/home')->with('success', 'Document has been deleted!!');
        }
```

Comment: For some reason it still ignores the action, instead it goes to the same controller as where the edit view gets passed from.

Comment: are you using another form on same page??

Comment: I fixed it. I simply used a nested form, I'm dumb.